# nodejs postgresql send secure parameters error

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I want to send parameters securly with postgresql to prevent sql injections.

if I send the parameter I will get this error Message: There is no Parameter $1

what do I am wrong?

```
'use strict';

const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'TEST',
    password: 'xxxx',
    port: 4551,
});

const Query = async query => {
    try {
        await pool.connect();

        const res = await pool.query('SELECT email FROM client WHERE email = $1', ["test@mail.com"]);
        console.log(res.rows[0]);
        await pool.end();
    } catch(e) {
        return e;
    }
};

module.exports = Query;
```

€: And should I use client or pool ?